# Compilation error on consuming and building .NetStandard library using MS Build

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, msbuild, class-library, .net-standard-2.0

I have a couple of projects in my solution, migrated one of the class library to .netstandard(ModelLib) which is consumed by .net472 class library(serviceLib). The serviceLib is again referenced by another .net472 class library(apiLib). This apiLib is used in my asp.net website project.

Now, build works fine in VSStudio 2019, but fails when building using MS Build in test environment.

I get the following error and Build log says:-

c:\buildagent\xxxx\xxxx\web.config(186,0): error ASPCONFIG : Error ASPConfig: Could not load file or assembly 'apiLib' or one of its dependencies, the system cannot find the file specified.

The webconfig looks like this and line#186 is

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
 <assemblies>
               <add assembly="apiLib" />
 </assemblies>
 </compilation>
```

I checked the file in bin folder, the apiLib is missing.

Is there any .net version compatibility issues here?

Anybody faced similar issues and why apiLib is not copied into bin ? Is it something related to .NetStandard Project? Please help at the earliest..

Note: I haven't changed any package reference style of apiLib or similar libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your web project directly referencing the apiLib project?

Comment: Yes. Its a website project.